# Invalid configuration `x86_64': machine `x86_64' not recognized

Tags: linux, software-installation

Compiling this: http://linux.softpedia.com/progDownload/Indexed-PDF-Creator-Download-1071.html

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~/tarBalls/ipdf-1.0.0> ./configure --build=x86_64
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64': machine `x86_64' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub x86_64 failed
```

on:

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~/> uname -a && cat /etc/issue
Linux linux-dopx 3.2.1-12-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 19 16:02:50 IST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Welcome to openSUSE 11.3 "Teal" - Kernel \r (\l).
```

`config.sub` is as follows:

```
> #! /bin/sh
# Configuration validation subroutine script, version 1.1.
#   Copyright (C) 1991, 92-97, 1998 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
# This file is (in principle) common to ALL GNU software.
# The presence of a machine in this file suggests that SOME GNU software
# can handle that machine.  It does not imply ALL GNU software can.
#
# This file is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330,
# Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA.

# As a special exception to the GNU General Public License, if you
# distribute this file as part of a program that contains a
# configuration script generated by Autoconf, you may include it under
# the same distribution terms that you use for the rest of that program.

# Configuration subroutine to validate and canonicalize a configuration type.
# Supply the specified configuration type as an argument.
# If it is invalid, we print an error message on stderr and exit with code 1.
# Otherwise, we print the canonical config type on stdout and succeed.

# This file is supposed to be the same for all GNU packages
# and recognize all the CPU types, system types and aliases
# that are meaningful with *any* GNU software.
# Each package is responsible for reporting which valid configurations
# it does not support.  The user should be able to distinguish
# a failure to support a valid configuration from a meaningless
# configuration.

# The goal of this file is to map all the various variations of a given
# machine specification into a single specification in the form:
#   CPU_TYPE-MANUFACTURER-OPERATING_SYSTEM
# or in some cases, the newer four-part form:
#   CPU_TYPE-MANUFACTURER-KERNEL-OPERATING_SYSTEM
# It is wrong to echo any other type of specification.

if [ x$1 = x ]
then
    echo Configuration name missing. 1>&2
    echo "Usage: $0 CPU-MFR-OPSYS" 1>&2
    echo "or     $0 ALIAS" 1>&2
    echo where ALIAS is a recognized configuration type. 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# First pass through any local machine types.
case $1 in
    *local*)
        echo $1
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac

# Separate what the user gave into CPU-COMPANY and OS or KERNEL-OS (if any).
# Here we must recognize all the valid KERNEL-OS combinations.
maybe_os=`echo $1 | sed 's/^\(.*\)-\([^-]*-[^-]*\)$/\2/'`
case $maybe_os in
  linux-gnu*)
    os=-$maybe_os
    basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed 's/^\(.*\)-\([^-]*-[^-]*\)$/\1/'`
    ;;
  *)
    basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed 's/-[^-]*$//'`
    if [ $basic_machine != $1 ]
    then os=`echo $1 | sed 's/.*-/-/'`
    else os=; fi
    ;;
esac

### Let's recognize common machines as not being operating systems so
### that things like config.sub decstation-3100 work.  We also
### recognize some manufacturers as not being operating systems, so we
### can provide default operating systems below.
case $os in
    -sun*os*)
        # Prevent following clause from handling this invalid input.
        ;;
    -dec* | -mips* | -sequent* | -encore* | -pc532* | -sgi* | -sony* | \
    -att* | -7300* | -3300* | -delta* | -motorola* | -sun[234]* | \
    -unicom* | -ibm* | -next | -hp | -isi* | -apollo | -altos* | \
    -convergent* | -ncr* | -news | -32* | -3600* | -3100* | -hitachi* |\
    -c[123]* | -convex* | -sun | -crds | -omron* | -dg | -ultra | -tti* | \
    -harris | -dolphin | -highlevel | -gould | -cbm | -ns | -masscomp | \
    -apple)
        os=
        basic_machine=$1
        ;;
    -hiux*)
        os=-hiuxwe2
        ;;
    -sco5)
        os=sco3.2v5
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86-.*/86-pc/'`
        ;;
    -sco4)
        os=-sco3.2v4
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86-.*/86-pc/'`
        ;;
    -sco3.2.[4-9]*)
        os=`echo $os | sed -e 's/sco3.2./sco3.2v/'`
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86-.*/86-pc/'`
        ;;
    -sco3.2v[4-9]*)
        # Don't forget version if it is 3.2v4 or newer.
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86-.*/86-pc/'`
        ;;
    -sco*)
        os=-sco3.2v2
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86-.*/86-pc/'`
        ;;
    -isc)
        os=-isc2.2
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86-.*/86-pc/'`
        ;;
    -clix*)
        basic_machine=clipper-intergraph
        ;;
    -isc*)
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86-.*/86-pc/'`
        ;;
    -lynx*)
        os=-lynxos
            ;;
    -ptx*)
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86-.*/86-sequent/'`
        ;;
    -windowsnt*)
        os=`echo $os | sed -e 's/windowsnt/winnt/'`
        ;;
    -psos*)
        os=-psos
        ;;
esac

# Decode aliases for certain CPU-COMPANY combinations.
case $basic_machine in
    # Recognize the basic CPU types without company name.
    # Some are omitted here because they have special meanings below.
    tahoe | i860 | m32r | m68k | m68000 | m88k | ns32k | arc | arm \
        | arme[lb] | pyramid | mn10200 | mn10300 | tron | a29k \
        | 580 | i960 | h8300 | hppa | hppa1.0 | hppa1.1 | hppa2.0 \
        | alpha | alphaev5 | alphaev56 | we32k | ns16k | clipper \
        | i370 | sh | powerpc | powerpcle | 1750a | dsp16xx | pdp11 \
        | mips64 | mipsel | mips64el | mips64orion | mips64orionel \
        | mipstx39 | mipstx39el \
        | sparc | sparclet | sparclite | sparc64 | v850)
        basic_machine=$basic_machine-unknown
        ;;
    # We use `pc' rather than `unknown'
    # because (1) that's what they normally are, and
    # (2) the word "unknown" tends to confuse beginning users.
    i[34567]86)
      basic_machine=$basic_machine-pc
      ;;
    # Object if more than one company name word.
    *-*-*)
        echo Invalid configuration \`$1\': machine \`$basic_machine\' not recognized 1>&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    # Recognize the basic CPU types with company name.
    vax-* | tahoe-* | i[34567]86-* | i860-* | m32r-* | m68k-* | m68000-* \
          | m88k-* | sparc-* | ns32k-* | fx80-* | arc-* | arm-* | c[123]* \
          | mips-* | pyramid-* | tron-* | a29k-* | romp-* | rs6000-* \
          | power-* | none-* | 580-* | cray2-* | h8300-* | i960-* \
          | xmp-* | ymp-* | hppa-* | hppa1.0-* | hppa1.1-* | hppa2.0-* \
          | alpha-* | alphaev5-* | alphaev56-* | we32k-* | cydra-* \
          | ns16k-* | pn-* | np1-* | xps100-* | clipper-* | orion-* \
          | sparclite-* | pdp11-* | sh-* | powerpc-* | powerpcle-* \
          | sparc64-* | mips64-* | mipsel-* \
          | mips64el-* | mips64orion-* | mips64orionel-*  \
          | mipstx39-* | mipstx39el-* \
          | f301-*)
        ;;
    # Recognize the various machine names and aliases which stand
    # for a CPU type and a company and sometimes even an OS.
    3b1 | 7300 | 7300-att | att-7300 | pc7300 | safari | unixpc)
        basic_machine=m68000-att
        ;;
    3b*)
        basic_machine=we32k-att
        ;;
    alliant | fx80)
        basic_machine=fx80-alliant
        ;;
    altos | altos3068)
        basic_machine=m68k-altos
        ;;
    am29k)
        basic_machine=a29k-none
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    amdahl)
        basic_machine=580-amdahl
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    amiga | amiga-*)
        basic_machine=m68k-cbm
        ;;
    amigaos | amigados)
        basic_machine=m68k-cbm
        os=-amigaos
        ;;
    amigaunix | amix)
        basic_machine=m68k-cbm
        os=-sysv4
        ;;
    apollo68)
        basic_machine=m68k-apollo
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    aux)
        basic_machine=m68k-apple
        os=-aux
        ;;
    balance)
        basic_machine=ns32k-sequent
        os=-dynix
        ;;
    convex-c1)
        basic_machine=c1-convex
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    convex-c2)
        basic_machine=c2-convex
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    convex-c32)
        basic_machine=c32-convex
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    convex-c34)
        basic_machine=c34-convex
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    convex-c38)
        basic_machine=c38-convex
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    cray | ymp)
        basic_machine=ymp-cray
        os=-unicos
        ;;
    cray2)
        basic_machine=cray2-cray
        os=-unicos
        ;;
    [ctj]90-cray)
        basic_machine=c90-cray
        os=-unicos
        ;;
    crds | unos)
        basic_machine=m68k-crds
        ;;
    da30 | da30-*)
        basic_machine=m68k-da30
        ;;
    decstation | decstation-3100 | pmax | pmax-* | pmin | dec3100 | decstatn)
        basic_machine=mips-dec
        ;;
    delta | 3300 | motorola-3300 | motorola-delta \
          | 3300-motorola | delta-motorola)
        basic_machine=m68k-motorola
        ;;
    delta88)
        basic_machine=m88k-motorola
        os=-sysv3
        ;;
    dpx20 | dpx20-*)
        basic_machine=rs6000-bull
        os=-bosx
        ;;
    dpx2* | dpx2*-bull)
        basic_machine=m68k-bull
        os=-sysv3
        ;;
    ebmon29k)
        basic_machine=a29k-amd
        os=-ebmon
        ;;
    elxsi)
        basic_machine=elxsi-elxsi
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    encore | umax | mmax)
            basic_machine=ns32k-encore
        ;;
    fx2800)
        basic_machine=i860-alliant
        ;;
    genix)
        basic_machine=ns32k-ns
        ;;
    gmicro)
        basic_machine=tron-gmicro
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    h3050r* | hiux*)
        basic_machine=hppa1.1-hitachi
        os=-hiuxwe2
        ;;
    h8300hms)
        basic_machine=h8300-hitachi
        os=-hms
        ;;
    harris)
        basic_machine=m88k-harris
        os=-sysv3
        ;;
    hp300-*)
        basic_machine=m68k-hp
        ;;
    hp300bsd)
        basic_machine=m68k-hp
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    hp300hpux)
        basic_machine=m68k-hp
        os=-hpux
        ;;
    hp9k2[0-9][0-9] | hp9k31[0-9])
        basic_machine=m68000-hp
        ;;
    hp9k3[2-9][0-9])
        basic_machine=m68k-hp
        ;;
    hp9k7[0-9][0-9] | hp7[0-9][0-9] | hp9k8[0-9]7 | hp8[0-9]7)
        basic_machine=hppa1.1-hp
        ;;
    hp9k8[0-9][0-9] | hp8[0-9][0-9])
        basic_machine=hppa1.0-hp
        ;;
    hppa-next)
            os=-nextstep3
        ;;
    i370-ibm* | ibm*)
        basic_machine=i370-ibm
        os=-mvs
        ;;
# I'm not sure what "Sysv32" means.  Should this be sysv3.2?
    i[34567]86v32)
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86.*/86-pc/'`
        os=-sysv32
        ;;
    i[34567]86v4*)
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86.*/86-pc/'`
        os=-sysv4
        ;;
    i[34567]86v)
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86.*/86-pc/'`
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    i[34567]86sol2)
        basic_machine=`echo $1 | sed -e 's/86.*/86-pc/'`
        os=-solaris2
        ;;
    iris | iris4d)
        basic_machine=mips-sgi
        case $os in
            -irix*)
            ;;
            *)
            os=-irix4
            ;;
        esac
        ;;
    isi68 | isi)
        basic_machine=m68k-isi
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    m88k-omron*)
        basic_machine=m88k-omron
        ;;
    magnum | m3230)
        basic_machine=mips-mips
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    merlin)
        basic_machine=ns32k-utek
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    miniframe)
        basic_machine=m68000-convergent
        ;;
    mipsel*-linux*)
        basic_machine=mipsel-unknown
        os=-linux-gnu
        ;;
    mips*-linux*)
        basic_machine=mips-unknown
        os=-linux-gnu
        ;;
    mips3*-*)
        basic_machine=`echo $basic_machine | sed -e 's/mips3/mips64/'`
        ;;
    mips3*)
        basic_machine=`echo $basic_machine | sed -e 's/mips3/mips64/'`-unknown
        ;;
    ncr3000)
        basic_machine=i486-ncr
        os=-sysv4
        ;;
    news | news700 | news800 | news900)
        basic_machine=m68k-sony
        os=-newsos
        ;;
    news1000)
        basic_machine=m68030-sony
        os=-newsos
        ;;
    news-3600 | risc-news)
        basic_machine=mips-sony
        os=-newsos
        ;;
    next | m*-next )
        basic_machine=m68k-next
        case $os in
            -nextstep* )
            ;;
            -ns2*)
              os=-nextstep2
            ;;
            *)
              os=-nextstep3
            ;;
        esac
        ;;
    nh3000)
        basic_machine=m68k-harris
        os=-cxux
        ;;
    nh[45]000)
        basic_machine=m88k-harris
        os=-cxux
        ;;
    nindy960)
        basic_machine=i960-intel
        os=-nindy
        ;;
    np1)
        basic_machine=np1-gould
        ;;
    pa-hitachi)
        basic_machine=hppa1.1-hitachi
        os=-hiuxwe2
        ;;
    paragon)
        basic_machine=i860-intel
        os=-osf
        ;;
    pbd)
        basic_machine=sparc-tti
        ;;
    pbb)
        basic_machine=m68k-tti
        ;;
        pc532 | pc532-*)
        basic_machine=ns32k-pc532
        ;;
    pentium | p5 | k5 | nexen)
        basic_machine=i586-pc
        ;;
    pentiumpro | p6 | k6 | 6x86)
        basic_machine=i686-pc
        ;;
    pentiumii | pentium2)
        basic_machine=i786-pc
        ;;
    pentium-* | p5-* | k5-* | nexen-*)
        basic_machine=i586-`echo $basic_machine | sed 's/^[^-]*-//'`
        ;;
    pentiumpro-* | p6-* | k6-* | 6x86-*)
        basic_machine=i686-`echo $basic_machine | sed 's/^[^-]*-//'`
        ;;
    pentiumii-* | pentium2-*)
        basic_machine=i786-`echo $basic_machine | sed 's/^[^-]*-//'`
        ;;
    pn)
        basic_machine=pn-gould
        ;;
    power)  basic_machine=rs6000-ibm
        ;;
    ppc)    basic_machine=powerpc-unknown
            ;;
    ppc-*)  basic_machine=powerpc-`echo $basic_machine | sed 's/^[^-]*-//'`
        ;;
    ppcle | powerpclittle | ppc-le | powerpc-little)
        basic_machine=powerpcle-unknown
            ;;
    ppcle-* | powerpclittle-*)
        basic_machine=powerpcle-`echo $basic_machine | sed 's/^[^-]*-//'`
        ;;
    ps2)
        basic_machine=i386-ibm
        ;;
    rm[46]00)
        basic_machine=mips-siemens
        ;;
    rtpc | rtpc-*)
        basic_machine=romp-ibm
        ;;
    sequent)
        basic_machine=i386-sequent
            ;;
    sh)
        basic_machine=sh-hitachi
        os=-hms
        ;;
    sps7)
        basic_machine=m68k-bull
        os=-sysv2
        ;;
    spur)
        basic_machine=spur-unknown
        ;;
    sun2)
        basic_machine=m68000-sun
        ;;
    sun2os3)
        basic_machine=m68000-sun
        os=-sunos3
        ;;
    sun2os4)
        basic_machine=m68000-sun
        os=-sunos4
        ;;
    sun3os3)
        basic_machine=m68k-sun
        os=-sunos3
        ;;
    sun3os4)
        basic_machine=m68k-sun
        os=-sunos4
        ;;
    sun4os3)
        basic_machine=sparc-sun
        os=-sunos3
        ;;
    sun4os4)
        basic_machine=sparc-sun
        os=-sunos4
        ;;
    sun4sol2)
        basic_machine=sparc-sun
        os=-solaris2
        ;;
    sun3 | sun3-*)
        basic_machine=m68k-sun
        ;;
    sun4)
        basic_machine=sparc-sun
        ;;
    sun386 | sun386i | roadrunner)
        basic_machine=i386-sun
        ;;
    symmetry)
        basic_machine=i386-sequent
        os=-dynix
        ;;
    tx39)
        basic_machine=mipstx39-unknown
        ;;
    tx39el)
        basic_machine=mipstx39el-unknown
        ;;
    tower | tower-32)
        basic_machine=m68k-ncr
        ;;
    udi29k)
        basic_machine=a29k-amd
        os=-udi
        ;;
    ultra3)
        basic_machine=a29k-nyu
        os=-sym1
        ;;
    vaxv)
        basic_machine=vax-dec
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    vms)
        basic_machine=vax-dec
        os=-vms
        ;;
    vpp*|vx|vx-*)
               basic_machine=f301-fujitsu
               ;;
    vxworks960)
        basic_machine=i960-wrs
        os=-vxworks
        ;;
    vxworks68)
        basic_machine=m68k-wrs
        os=-vxworks
        ;;
    vxworks29k)
        basic_machine=a29k-wrs
        os=-vxworks
        ;;
    xmp)
        basic_machine=xmp-cray
        os=-unicos
        ;;
        xps | xps100)
        basic_machine=xps100-honeywell
        ;;
    none)
        basic_machine=none-none
        os=-none
        ;;

# Here we handle the default manufacturer of certain CPU types.  It is in
# some cases the only manufacturer, in others, it is the most popular.
    mips)
        if [ x$os = x-linux-gnu ]; then
            basic_machine=mips-unknown
        else
            basic_machine=mips-mips
        fi
        ;;
    romp)
        basic_machine=romp-ibm
        ;;
    rs6000)
        basic_machine=rs6000-ibm
        ;;
    vax)
        basic_machine=vax-dec
        ;;
    pdp11)
        basic_machine=pdp11-dec
        ;;
    we32k)
        basic_machine=we32k-att
        ;;
    sparc)
        basic_machine=sparc-sun
        ;;
        cydra)
        basic_machine=cydra-cydrome
        ;;
    orion)
        basic_machine=orion-highlevel
        ;;
    orion105)
        basic_machine=clipper-highlevel
        ;;
    *)
        echo Invalid configuration \`$1\': machine \`$basic_machine\' not recognized 1>&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

# Here we canonicalize certain aliases for manufacturers.
case $basic_machine in
    *-digital*)
        basic_machine=`echo $basic_machine | sed 's/digital.*/dec/'`
        ;;
    *-commodore*)
        basic_machine=`echo $basic_machine | sed 's/commodore.*/cbm/'`
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

# Decode manufacturer-specific aliases for certain operating systems.

if [ x"$os" != x"" ]
then
case $os in
        # First match some system type aliases
        # that might get confused with valid system types.
    # -solaris* is a basic system type, with this one exception.
    -solaris1 | -solaris1.*)
        os=`echo $os | sed -e 's|solaris1|sunos4|'`
        ;;
    -solaris)
        os=-solaris2
        ;;
    -svr4*)
        os=-sysv4
        ;;
    -unixware*)
        os=-sysv4.2uw
        ;;
    -gnu/linux*)
        os=`echo $os | sed -e 's|gnu/linux|linux-gnu|'`
        ;;
    # First accept the basic system types.
    # The portable systems comes first.
    # Each alternative MUST END IN A *, to match a version number.
    # -sysv* is not here because it comes later, after sysvr4.
    -gnu* | -bsd* | -mach* | -minix* | -genix* | -ultrix* | -irix* \
          | -*vms* | -sco* | -esix* | -isc* | -aix* | -sunos | -sunos[34]*\
          | -hpux* | -unos* | -osf* | -luna* | -dgux* | -solaris* | -sym* \
          | -amigaos* | -amigados* | -msdos* | -newsos* | -unicos* | -aof* \
          | -aos* \
          | -nindy* | -vxsim* | -vxworks* | -ebmon* | -hms* | -mvs* \
          | -clix* | -riscos* | -uniplus* | -iris* | -rtu* | -xenix* \
          | -hiux* | -386bsd* | -netbsd* | -openbsd* | -freebsd* | -riscix* \
          | -lynxos* | -bosx* | -nextstep* | -cxux* | -aout* | -elf* \
          | -ptx* | -coff* | -ecoff* | -winnt* | -domain* | -vsta* \
          | -udi* | -eabi* | -lites* | -ieee* | -go32* | -aux* \
          | -cygwin* | -pe* | -psos* | -moss* | -proelf* | -rtems* \
          | -mingw32* | -linux-gnu* | -uxpv* | -beos* | -rhapsody* \
          | -openstep*)
    # Remember, each alternative MUST END IN *, to match a version number.
        ;;
    -linux*)
        os=`echo $os | sed -e 's|linux|linux-gnu|'`
        ;;
    -sunos5*)
        os=`echo $os | sed -e 's|sunos5|solaris2|'`
        ;;
    -sunos6*)
        os=`echo $os | sed -e 's|sunos6|solaris3|'`
        ;;
    -osfrose*)
        os=-osfrose
        ;;
    -osf*)
        os=-osf
        ;;
    -utek*)
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    -dynix*)
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    -acis*)
        os=-aos
        ;;
    -ctix* | -uts*)
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    -ns2 )
            os=-nextstep2
        ;;
    # Preserve the version number of sinix5.
    -sinix5.*)
        os=`echo $os | sed -e 's|sinix|sysv|'`
        ;;
    -sinix*)
        os=-sysv4
        ;;
    -triton*)
        os=-sysv3
        ;;
    -oss*)
        os=-sysv3
        ;;
    -svr4)
        os=-sysv4
        ;;
    -svr3)
        os=-sysv3
        ;;
    -sysvr4)
        os=-sysv4
        ;;
    # This must come after -sysvr4.
    -sysv*)
        ;;
    -xenix)
        os=-xenix
        ;;
    -none)
        ;;
    *)
        # Get rid of the `-' at the beginning of $os.
        os=`echo $os | sed 's/[^-]*-//'`
        echo Invalid configuration \`$1\': system \`$os\' not recognized 1>&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
else

# Here we handle the default operating systems that come with various machines.
# The value should be what the vendor currently ships out the door with their
# machine or put another way, the most popular os provided with the machine.

# Note that if you're going to try to match "-MANUFACTURER" here (say,
# "-sun"), then you have to tell the case statement up towards the top
# that MANUFACTURER isn't an operating system.  Otherwise, code above
# will signal an error saying that MANUFACTURER isn't an operating
# system, and we'll never get to this point.

c    ase $basic_machine in
    *-acorn)
        os=-riscix1.2
        ;;
    arm*-semi)
        os=-aout
        ;;
        pdp11-*)
        os=-none
        ;;
    *-dec | vax-*)
        os=-ultrix4.2
        ;;
    m68*-apollo)
        os=-domain
        ;;
    i386-sun)
        os=-sunos4.0.2
        ;;
    m68000-sun)
        os=-sunos3
        # This also exists in the configure program, but was not the
        # default.
        # os=-sunos4
        ;;
    *-tti)  # must be before sparc entry or we get the wrong os.
        os=-sysv3
        ;;
    sparc-* | *-sun)
        os=-sunos4.1.1
        ;;
    *-be)
        os=-beos
        ;;
    *-ibm)
        os=-aix
        ;;
    *-hp)
        os=-hpux
        ;;
    *-hitachi)
        os=-hiux
        ;;
    i860-* | *-att | *-ncr | *-altos | *-motorola | *-convergent)
        os=-sysv
        ;;
    *-cbm)
        os=-amigaos
        ;;
    *-dg)
        os=-dgux
        ;;
    *-dolphin)
        os=-sysv3
        ;;
    m68k-ccur)
        os=-rtu
        ;;
    m88k-omron*)
        os=-luna
        ;;
    *-next )
        os=-nextstep
        ;;
    *-sequent)
        os=-ptx
        ;;
    *-crds)
        os=-unos
        ;;
    *-ns)
        os=-genix
        ;;
    i370-*)
        os=-mvs
        ;;
    *-next)
        os=-nextstep3
        ;;
        *-gould)
        os=-sysv
        ;;
        *-highlevel)
        os=-bsd
        ;;
    *-encore)
        os=-bsd
        ;;
            *-sgi)
        os=-irix
        ;;
        *-siemens)
        os=-sysv4
        ;;
    *-masscomp)
        os=-rtu
        ;;
    f301-fujitsu)
        os=-uxpv
        ;;
    *)
        os=-none
        ;;
esac
fi

# Here we handle the case where we know the os, and the CPU type, but not the
# manufacturer.  We pick the logical manufacturer.
vendor=unknown
case $basic_machine in
    *-unknown)
        case $os in
            -riscix*)
                vendor=acorn
                ;;
            -sunos*)
                vendor=sun
                ;;
            -aix*)
                vendor=ibm
                ;;
            -hpux*)
                vendor=hp
                ;;
            -hiux*)
                vendor=hitachi
                ;;
            -unos*)
                vendor=crds
                ;;
            -dgux*)
                vendor=dg
                ;;
            -luna*)
                vendor=omron
                ;;
            -genix*)
                vendor=ns
                ;;
            -mvs*)
                vendor=ibm
                ;;
            -ptx*)
                vendor=sequent
                ;;
            -vxsim* | -vxworks*)
                vendor=wrs
                ;;
                -aux*)
                vendor=apple
                ;;
        esac
        basic_machine=`echo $basic_machine | sed "s/unknown/$vendor/"`
        ;;
esac

echo $basic_machine$os
```

Comment: Configure should *guess* the appropriate arch, unless your cross compiling.

Comment: @bdowning `Which distro are you using?  What is your arch?` Read the second code of the OP.

Comment: How does the configure fail w/o specifying --build=

Comment: That package on softpedia hasn't been updated since 2005, probably not 64 bit savvy

Comment: I tried ./configure --build=i386 and it passed, but then failed at error: Could not find libpdf.  

That's definitely not maintained, and it's 32bit software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `./configure` without the `--build` argument?

From [the projects](http://hoopajoo.net/projects/ipdf.html)(1) `INSTALL` instructions:

> If you are building compiler tools for cross-compiling, you can also
>   use the `--target=TYPE` option to select the type of system they will
>   produce code for and the `--build=TYPE` option to select the type of
>   system on which you are compiling the package.

From what I gather about your system from your question, you don't need to crossbuild, so a simple `./configure` in the toplevel directory could actually do the trick (or yield new errors, fails with `Invalid configuration 'amd64-unknown-freebsd8.2': machine 'amd64-unknown' not recognized` here...portable? seems not).

(1) Did I guess the right project?  This softpedia website is kind of weird.

---

**Edit:** As you observed, the project seems pretty bit-rotten.  You could try to look for an alternative.  If your problem is "converting a plain text file to a PDF document", [some Perl module for PDF creation](http://search.cpan.org/~markusb/PDF-Create-1.06/lib/PDF/Create.pm#Other_PDF_procesing_CPAN_modules) could be a way to go, as Perl is well-suited for plain text processing.  (And there is ([La](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX))[TeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) and [ConTeXt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConTeXt), of course.)

Comment: I had linked the project in OP. I did --build because ./configure didn't work on its own, shows same errors. WOW the history date of latest tar on your link goes back to 2003!!!

Comment: @AnishaKaul: Your `softpedia.com` link unfortunately is a bit misleading, as it states "Last update: Aug 2011" while the tarball you download in the end is the exact same file as the 2003 download on the program's author's website.

Comment: The project is indeed ROTTEN :mad:

Answer (score -2):

I had similar error, no crash:

```
../configure --with-gtk=3 --with-cxx=11  --with-pic=yes --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-compat28 -enable-unicode  --build=x86_64      --prefix=mypath/opt
```

> machine `mypath/opt' not recognized
>
> configure: error: /bin/sh ../config.sub /home/alexb/opt failed
>   OI

add --build=x86_64 option(do not remember where I found it.) and eliminate space after '--prefix='

Comment: Actually had better results if type in --target=x86_64 instead of --build=...