# How to create indexes in a pdf?

Tags: pdf, free-software

[iPdf is rotten](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31084/invalid-configuration-x86-64-machine-x86-64-not-recognized).

Is there any other software or any other way by which an "**index**" can be created in a pdf file?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? (Maybe example input or more details...)

Comment: @sr_ I am talking about the index which we see on the front pages of a book. The index tells which chapter is on which page. In Pdf, we "can" click the chapters shown on the indexes, and that takes us to the exact chapter.

Comment: Ok, so you start with a PDF file and want to create a PDF file that adds a *table of contents* (in front) to the original file...Did I get it right? `:)`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11082/adding-table-of-contents-to-existing-pdf/11084#11084

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use LaTeX. Refer [this](http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/contents) for more detail. First install LaTeX and then follow tutorial. Finding LaTeX is not difficult for most distributions.

If you want to Click-and-Reference, refer [this.](http://dsanta.users.ch/resources/hyperref.html)

Comment: And if you have further questions, http://tex.stackexchange.com exists

Answer (score 5):

PDF Mod worked well for me. The entries I see left when reading pdfs in document viewer are called "bookmarks" in the program and can be edited at will, just pick a title and the corresponding page to jump to.

You can have an index that updates itself if you create a table of contents in Open Office. I've notice these will be converted to the index you describe when the document is published or exported to a pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/#Foxit-Reader/), available in Windows, Mac OS, and Linux.

When you create *bookmarks* in Foxit Reader, they appear as an *Index* in the common .pdf viewers.

1. Open the .pdf file with Foxit Reader
2. Open the *Bookmarks NAvigation Panel* in Menu `Tools > Navigation Panels > Bookmarks`
3. Now you can use the icons to create and name Bookmarks and you can move the bookmarks around and nest them, in order to create a bookmark hierarchy. (as Index are usually hierarchic: chapter, section, subsection)

**Caveat:** For long and very nested indexes can be buggy in Linux, because is not the original platform.